# Virtual Host for SimpleSAMLPHP

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost, httpd.conf

I want to install SimpleSAMLPHP on my apache2, I don't have a lot of experience on server config and need to ask if this is correct for virtual host setup:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName service.mywebsite.ca
        DocumentRoot “/home/mywebsite/public_html”

        Alias /simplesaml /var/simplesamlphp/www
</VirtualHost>
```

Basically I need all request from

```
service.mywebsite.ca/simplesaml
```

to hit the default simplesamlphp install directory.  There are lot of other services on the server setup by someone else so I need to make sure it does not break anything.

Comment: Looks OK to me, what seems to be the problem?

Comment: Oh I haven't tried it yet, I just wanted to ask if this is correct before I add it to httpd.conf

Comment: You should show some research when you post here. Usually when one asks a question, it's about something not working as expected. Questions in the form of `will this work with my system` cannot be answered reliably other than references to the documentation. This is simply because there are too many factors that may change the outcome. If there is something unusual about your setup, include it in your question. At any rate, i'd suggest trying before posting here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [simpleSAMLphp installation procedure](https://simplesamlphp.org/docs/stable/simplesamlphp-install#section_6) is documented on the [simpleSAMLphp website](https://simplesamlphp.org/). It states there that only the `www` folder has to be available from the internet, which can be achieved by aliassing `/simplesaml`. It looks like you're doing that.

Not knowing anything about your setup, I can not possibly know if you won't break anything by doing this. Normally, in a professional setting, you'd have a test system to try these kinds of things out before rolling out to production. Your setup looks like this:

- `service.mywebsite.ca/` -> `/home/mywebsite/public_html`
- `service.mywebsite.ca/simplesaml/` -> `/var/simplesamlphp/www`

If that makes sense to you, you're probably fine.

Small note, I noticed that you use fancy quotes (`”`) in your config file. These won't work, you'll need normal quotes (`"`). It can be that your webbrowser replaced them when you pasted code on this site, but it's something to be aware of.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed reassurance, I'll give it a try.